# SQL Server start job at specific step using bat script

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, jobs

I am trying execute the SQL Server job using a batch command. I use this command to call a job.

```
osql -S “[SQL SERVER NAME]” -E -Q”exec msdb.dbo.sp_start_job ‘[SQL JOB NAME]‘”
```

But I want to skip the first 4 steps, instead I want to start the job from step 5.

Comment: First 4 steps? Are we supposed to guess what you mean?

Comment: Job consists of many steps. But i don't want to execute first 4 steps. I want to start the job from 5th step.

Comment: So, pass a parameter to the JOB indicating that the starting step is "5".

Comment: As of SQL Server **2005**, you should **stop using** `osql` and `isql` and instead use `sqlcmd`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `step_name` parameter :

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'your_job_name', @step_name='step_name'
```

[image]

**Example:** `EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @job_name = 'myJob', @step_name='Insert into TGR0'` to start from step 2.

Comment: how-to get if job finished (success or failure) ?